# What do I do when I'm being insulted in a post?

Tags: discussion, offensive

I am getting attacked. I have seen this happening quite a bit lately, but usually only in the comments though. How do we educate people on how this site works?

[image]

Comment: Flag and move on.

Comment: *"How do we educate people on how this site works?"* To be honest, I wouldn't waste my time on trying to educate these people. They should only be kicked/banned and then be forgotten. Everything else is just wasted effort and time. And we need that time to help other people who appreciate it.

Comment: its on the help-page... http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: This is exactly why flags exist so the fact that you had to ask this question may indicate that the site's efforts to educate people are _already_ failing in some way. Honest question, Colin: why did you feel the need to ask this? Did you not know that you could flag posts? Or did you not know what flags do? Did you think that there should be some special channel for handling direct abuse? If you could share your perspective on this I think it might help us help the community use SE sites more effectively. (I'm a mod on another site, not SO)

Comment: This is what happens when 12 years old start using the internet...As solution, I suggest calling their parents to ground them for bad behavior.

Comment: I know the intentions of the user are to insult you, but please, realize that "gay" is not (and should not be) an insult.

Comment: @Ander Biguri: Silence is better than bullshit.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari hum? You mean that the user should not have insulted? yeah of course, I was just making a side note...

Comment: My comment was deleted which I think it is offensive :(

Comment: people like `a rom` should get some `viva puffs`... (I know that comment will be deleted. The `deleter` should get some `viva puffs` too... not because the `deleter` is evil, but just because they are so good...)

Comment: School started for a lot of people and I think most of them flocked to SO to get help with their first assignments. Not a lot of fun for people trying to contribute. Maybe one day teachers will give a class on how to conduct on SO. Until then I don't answer question from people with a rep lower than 50 in September.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

We are very sorry you are being attacked for contributing to the community.

There is nothing we can do as a community except flagging the answer as rude / abusive. If this happens a lot from the same user, you can flag with a custom message and tell the moderator about you being the subject of abuse.

You can also contact the team using the *Contact Us* at the bottom of every page to contact the SE team. They have more abilities than moderators, but please don't use them unless you really have to. Usually moderators know when they should involve the SE team.

And please, don't let these people get you down. There are plenty people that do want your help!

Comment: I personally think this is a case where the user should be instantly banned, not warned. StackOverflow is a volunteer community so literally none of us (barring a few employees who probably aren't answering questions) get paid to put up with abuse like this. It is a privilege to use the site for help, not a right. If the above user is so concerned with the ability to post here, perhaps they should have thought for 5 seconds before using it to post hate speech.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, the user was not only warned -- they were suspended, and will remain so for four more days. I believe it's actually a good thing we don't go for the exile button at the first offense. Everyone makes mistakes, especially when they're led by anger, and (some) people can improve when given the chance to. That said, persisting in that behavior would be a very bad idea and would most probably result in far longer suspension at best, outright account destruction at worst.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's good, and to be clear I'm commenting more on the suggestion in the answer here than what actions were actually taken (which I was not privy to). As for zero-tolerance exiling, all you need to create a new account is another email address, so I don't think of account destruction as banning someone from the site forever.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, [the system keeps track of users at a lower level than the email address](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/). I'm pretty sure the dev team and possibly the mods would be able to recoup the two accounts, unless the user hides behind different proxies or changes their ISP. And even then, the system may be monitoring individual navigation patterns... ;)

Comment: I agree with Two-Bit. 4 Days feels a little light for this user (http://stackoverflow.com/users/5278774/a-rom). I would have rather seen 180 at least. There are mistakes and then there are serious concerns. This situation is the latter and there should be no slaps on the wrist for that type of behavior in this community.